Inserting substring into string by pointer not working
I am currently trying to use C to write a function that inserts a substring into a string given the string, substring, and the position the substring is to be inserted. I am trying to manipulate the string with pointers by accessing their addresses and changing the values stored in the address, but it seems to be not working, and I'm not very sure where went wrong. Does it have anything to do with the fact that strings are immutable, or is there just some error in the program?
For example, if string were to be "Hello !" and the substring to be "world", and the substring is to be inserted at the position 6 (!), the output should be "Hello world!".
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void strInsert(char string[], char fragment[], int position) {
    char *stringptr, *destptr, *ptr;
    int i;
    stringptr = string;
    destptr = string;
    ptr = fragment;
    for (i = (int)strlen(string) - 1; i >= position; i--) {
        stringptr = &string[i];
        destptr = &string[(int)strlen(fragment) + i];
        *destptr = *stringptr;
    }
    for (i = position; i < (int)strlen(fragment) - 1; i++) {
        stringptr = &string[i];
        ptr = &fragment[i - position];
        *stringptr = *ptr;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[1000];
    char fragment[255];
    int pos;
    fgets(string, 1000, stdin);
    while (isspace(string[(int)strlen(string) - 1]))
        string[(int)strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';
    fgets(fragment, 255, stdin);
    while (isspace(fragment[(int)strlen(fragment) - 1]))
        fragment[(int)strlen(fragment) - 1] = '\0';
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    printf("Before strInsert(), Original string: [%s]\n", string);
    printf("Before strInsert(), Fragment string: [%s]\n", fragment);
    strInsert(string, fragment, pos);
    printf("After strInsert(): [%s]\n", string);
    return 0;
}


String literals are of type const char *, so you’d get a compiler warning or error attempting to pass them into this function. If you’re asking if there’s a problem in your program, well, you haven’t shown your whole program (or even how you’re calling this function), so there’s no way to know. You should always give a [mre] with relevant output/errors when asking for debugging help.

I have edited to provide more information. The problem I have found is, I can't seem to insert the substring into the string using the pointers.

What happens? Do you get a compiler error, wrong output, crash, or what? Be specific!

When I print out the string at printf("After strInsert(): [%s]\n", string);, only a part of the string is shown (only "Hello !"), yet when I add a few lines of code in the function to print out each character in string, I see that the first part of the function (moving the characters back to make space to insert substring) does work, but there isn't any change after running the second part (inserting the substring into the string)

@nneonneo: The type of the array induced by a character string literal in C is char [n]. Due to history, it is not const char [n]. In C++, it is const char [n].

@EricPostpischil I was referring to the type you get when passing a string literal into a function; I should’ve been more clear. You’re right that the literal itself is an array type.

@VTG the bounds on your second for loop are wrong. You need to add position to the fragment length.

@nneonneo: The type after automatic conversion to a pointer is char *, not const char *.

@EricPostpischil Ack, I’m clearly out of it. Sorry! Thanks for the clarification.

No need to cast the return of strlen() to int in your code, simply drop the casts and make size_t i; Avoid casts unless absolutely necessary (and that is rare if ever while you are learning C). The reason is a cast can mask a real type issue that the compiler will no longer issue a diagnostic for because you have told the compiler not to bother, you know what you are doing....

There are multiple problems in your code:

the loops to strip the trailing whitespace in the strings read by fgets have undefined behavior if the user input only contains whitespace.  You must add a test on the string length:
for (size_t len = strlen(string); len > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)string[len - 1]; len--) {
    string[len - 1] = '\0';
}

note however that inserting whitespace should be possible so the only character you mean to remove is the trailing newline, which can be done in a single step:
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';


the loops in function strInsert are obscured by the fact that you do not use temporary variables to store the string lengths.

the first loop does the appropriate copying of the trailing portion of the destination string, but it does not copy the null terminator.

the second loop does not copy the last character of the string to insert.

string positions and lengths should have type size_t and the fragment argument should be declared as const char *fragment to allow passing constant strings.

the char argument to isspace should be cast as (unsigned char) to avoid undefined behavior for negative values on architectures where char is signed.


Here is a modified version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strInsert(char *string, const char *fragment, size_t position) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(string);
    size_t len2 = string(fragment);
    if (position > len1)
        position = len1;
    /* move len1 + 1 - position character, including the null terminator */
    for (size_t i = len1 + 1; i-- > position;) {
        string[i + len2] = string[i];
    }
    /* copy the fragment in position */
    for (i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        string[position + i] = fragment[i];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[1000];
    char fragment[255];
    size_t pos;

    if (!fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin))
        return 1;
    string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';

    if (!fgets(fragment, sizeof fragment, stdin))
        return 1;
    fragment[strcspn(fragment, "\n")] = '\0';

    if (scanf("%zu", &pos) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Before strInsert(), original string: [%s]\n", string);
    printf("Before strInsert(), fragment string: [%s]\n", fragment);
    strInsert(string, fragment, pos);
    printf("After strInsert(): [%s]\n", string);
    return 0;
}

If the combined lengths of the string and fragment exceed 999 characters, the behavior is undefined. Passing the destination size and testing for this condition is recommended.
Here is a modified version that truncates the result and returns a flag to report this condition:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strInsert(char *string, size_t size, const char *fragment, size_t position) {
    size_t len1;     // initial length of destination string
    size_t len2;     // length of fragment to insert
    int status = 0;  // return value: -1 for truncation
    char *end = memchr(string, '\0', size); // try and find the null terminator
    if (end == NULL) {
        /* original string is not null terminated */
        status = -1;
        if (size == 0) {
            /* no space in destination buffer, do nothing */
            return status;
        }
        /* truncate destination string */
        len1 = size - 1;
    } else {
        len1 = end - string;
    }
    if (position > len1) {
        /* inserting past the end: append fragment */
        position = len1;
    }
    len2 = strlen(fragment);  // length of fragment to insert
    if (len1 + len2 >= size) {
        /* not enough space to insert: determine how to truncate */
        status = -1;
        if (position + len2 >= size) {
            /* truncate fragment, no trailing portion */
            len2 = size - position - 1;
            len1 = 0;
        } else {
            /* truncate trailing portion */
            len1 = size - len2 - 1;
        }
    }
    /* set the null terminator */
    string[len1 + len2] = '\0';
    /* move the trailing characters (right to left) */
    // memmove(string + position + len2, string + position, len1 - position);
    for (size_t i = len1; i-- > position;) {
        string[i + len2] = string[i];
    }
    /* copy the fragment at position */
    // memcpy(string + position, fragment, len2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        string[i + position] = fragment[i];
    }
    return status;
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[32];
    char fragment[32];
    size_t pos;

    if (!fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin))
        return 1;
    string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';

    if (!fgets(fragment, sizeof fragment, stdin))
        return 1;
    fragment[strcspn(fragment, "\n")] = '\0';

    if (scanf("%zu", &pos) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Before strInsert(), original string: [%s]\n", string);
    printf("Before strInsert(), fragment string: [%s]\n", fragment);
    if (strInsert(string, sizeof string, fragment, pos))
        printf("strInsert() reported truncation\n");
    printf("After strInsert(): [%s]\n", string);
    return 0;
}


It is hard to read and so complicated!
Here you have simple implementation. It is much easier if you split logic into functions
char *insert(char *str, const char *fr, const size_t pos)
{
    size_t frLen = strlen(fr);

    strmove(str + pos + frLen, str + pos, strlen(str) - pos + 1);
    memcpy(str + pos, fr, frLen);
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[64] = "Hello World!";

    printf("%s\n", insert(str, "-=+!@#############" , 7));
}

Remarks:

str must be long enough to accommodate the whole string. It has to be writable (string literals are not)
use size_t for indexes, sizes and positions
you should add some checks - for NULL pointers, if position is not past str etc
void strInsert(char string[],  it is the same as char *string. In C arrays are passed by pointer.

you can later write your own memcpy and strmove
char *strmove(char *, const char *s, const size_t n) 
{
    for (size_t i = n; i > 0; i--) 
    {
        d[i - 1] = s[i - 1];
    }

    return dest;
}


Pedantic:  add restrict to char *str, const char *fr.

Add "own .... memmove"?! -->mymemmove() does not handle, in general, overlapped data well like memmove().  Here it might be OK.  Of course if pos is beyond strlen(str), we have more trouble.

@0___________: Reverse will work for any destination... not really.  Reverse copy does not work if the source overlaps the end of the destination.

In this particular case, your implementation works, but naming it mymemmove is misleading because, as chux commented, it does not emulate the standard memmove function's behavior.  Your next comment might even be misconstrued as reverse copy solves the memcpy issues in all cases, just inefficiently, which is incorrect.  These issues are tricky and cause subtle bugs, let's try and avoid potential confusion for less savvy readers.

@0___________: let's clean the comments.
